# Using instanceType for return value fails if using self. Why?

Tags: objective-c, clang, xcode4.5

```
static NSMutableDictionary * allTheSingletons;
@implementation BGSuperSingleton

+(instancetype)singleton
{
    return [self singleton1];
}
+(id) singleton1
{
    NSString* className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);

    if (!allTheSingletons)
    {
        allTheSingletons = NSMutableDictionary.dictionary;
    }

    id result = allTheSingletons[className];

    PO(result);
    if (result==nil)
    {
        result = [[[self class] alloc]init];
        allTheSingletons[className]=result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

BGSuperSingleton should be the parents of all singleton classes.

Then I do in one of the subclass:

```
+(NSPredicate *)withinASquare:(double)distance{
    CLLocation * anchorWeUsed=[self singleton].mapCenterLocation; //Error map center is not of type ID
    return [self withinASquare:distance fromLocation:anchorWeUsed];
}
```

It looks like CLANG doesn't understand that singleton is of type `+(instancetype)` and think the type is id instead.

What am I missing?

Replacing `self` with the `MySubSingletonClass` (which is something that's known at compile time) works though.

Any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure (and all the beneath are only my assumptions) but seems that at compile time compiler does not know the class of `[self singleton1]`.
As it's said in [docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#related-result-types) (if we extrapolate that behavior on `instancetype` also):

> ... and the method will have a related result type **if its return type is compatible with the type of its class**...

I.e. `singleton1` returns object of an unknown class and `singleton` as well considers that it returns object of incompatible to `BGSuperSingleton` class  (as far as it's unknown at compile time), thus related result magic is not working here.

Was interested in that and also checked:

```
+ (NSPredicate*) withinASquare: (double)distance {
    CLLocation* anchorWeUsed = [[self alloc] init].mapCenterLocation; // Error map center is not of type ID
    return [self withinASquare:distance fromLocation:anchorWeUsed];
}
```

`alloc` and `init` return related result class and the error is still there. The thing helped was:

```
+ (NSPredicate*) withinASquare: (double)distance {
    BGSuperSingleton* bgSuperSingleton = [[self alloc] init]; // class is known at compile time
    CLLocation* anchorWeUsed = bgSuperSingleton.mapCenterLocation; // no error here
    return [self withinASquare:distance fromLocation:anchorWeUsed];
}
```

I'm still interested in this and hope somebody could approve or correct my **assumptions**.